# Windows Azure mobile services connecting existing database and accessing view?

Tags: sql-server, windows, azure

Hi I have connected my existing database with windows azure services by changing the schema but I can't get the views to work on windows azure. Anyone have any tutorial of how get the views to show up?

Answer (score 0):

I have been told by a MS person that the native UI doesn't support views. You can however develop your own custom api using node and mssql to access the database (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554226.aspx ).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that lands on this page, don't worry if your view portrait as a table on azure mobile services doesn't show any data. When you actually query it through your application it works just fine.